# Função playsound

Tags: c++, winforms

Estou a a programa um jogo para trabalho de escola em C++, e tenho um jogo que durante a sua execução inicia uma música, depois quando clico na tecla de espaço para disparar a música pára e só se ouve o tiro da arma.

Eu queria poder jogar com ambas as musicas tanto de fundo como as do jogo.

Aqui está o meu código:

```
private: System::Void GameForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    PlaySound(TEXT("../Musicas/Game.wav"), NULL, SND_ASYNC | SND_LOOP);
}
```

Esta música começa quando abro a página. E esta quando carrego no espaço:

```
private: System::Void GameForm_KeyDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e) 
{
    switch (e->KeyCode)
    {
    case Keys::A:
        Nave->Left -= 20;
        break;
    case Keys::D:
        Nave->Left += 20;
        break;
    case Keys::W:
        Nave->Top -= 20;
        break;
    case Keys::S:
        Nave->Top += 20;
        break;
    case Keys::Space://Carrego no espaço e o som e executado
        PlaySound(TEXT("../Musicas/Laser.wav"), NULL, SND_ASYNC);
        break;
    }
}
```

A música de fundo para quando executo o espaço. Queria as duas músicas ao mesmo tempo.

Answer (score 2):

Ao invés de usar a *flag* `SND_ASYNC`, use `SND_NOSTOP`.

Segundo a [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx):

> <sub>`SND_NOSTOP`</sub>
>
> The specified sound event will yield to another sound event that is
>   already playing in the same process. [ ... ].
>
> If this flag is not specified, `PlaySound` **attempts
>   to stop any sound that is currently playing in the same process**.
>   Sounds played in other processes are not affected.

Use assim:

```
PlaySound(TEXT("../Musicas/Laser.wav"), NULL, SND_NOSTOP);
```

Comment: já experimentei essa opção e não resultou

Comment: @kingwarrior05 Já tentou assim `PlaySound(..., NULL, SND_ASYNC | SND_NOSTOP)`?

Comment: sim já experimentei, quando substituo fico sem poder ouvir os tiros

Comment: @kingwarrior05 Pesquisando mais a fundo, parece que o `PlaySound` não suporta múltiplos sons ao mesmo tempo. (Veja [essa discussão](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/de87d08e-dab6-4b4e-948a-3ef4142b7e04/how-could-i-mutiple-sounds-with-playsound?forum=vclanguage)). Talvez seja necessário usar uma API mais sofisticada como o [DirectSound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416975(v=vs.85).aspx) ou [OpenAL](https://www.openal.org/), ou então o [**XAudio2**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415802(v=vs.85).aspx). :/

Answer (score 1):

A resposta à sua dúvida é extremamente simples: tem de criar dois construtores para cada uma das layers de sons que quer reproduzir em simultâneo, e definir o contexto em que estes vão ser instanciados. Só dessa forma poderá correr dois objectos em simultâneo, de forma a que quando o segundo o objecto é instanciado, não seja feito um override do primeiro. Para dar uma resposta com exemplos mais específicos, precisaria de aceder ao projecto, mas à partida é isso, uma vez que eu próprio passei por uma situação idêntica para instanciar duas vozes de um algoritmo para gerar midi proceduralmente, em c++, indo de encontro à estética da música de steve reich, partindo de código que tinha sido implementado em MaxMSP. boa sorte

Comment: você está a dizer que devia fazer uma classe a parte só para execução de som?

Comment: não aquilo que estaria a dizer, é que deveria ter um construtor para cada layer de som trigado, caso o objecto em causa não suportasse a reprodução de ficheiros múltiplos em simultâneo, mas como suporta, creio que a outra solução seja mai viável. eu apenas pensei de forma análoga à forma como resolvi um problema de envio de múltiplos canais midi a partir de c++ com a biblioteca rtmidi. contudo estamos a falar de implementações diferentes, e suportando o objecto o disparar de sons sem "re-trigger", ou seja sem cancelar o som anteriormente reproduzido, não há necessidade desta solução

Comment: o único contexto onde pode fazer sentido, é eventualmente numa lógica de estruturação de código, mas isso fica ao seu critério